# Add specific row data for a specific column value

Tags: python, csv

[image: CSV image]

Hi everyone,
I'm new to python.
When I find a specific value in the column `comm_rate`, I want to add the `utility_name` and `zip` to print out, like the example below. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is the link for the CSV [file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuxujzWVHKqPgeAk9GEPPTXceTtoKg?e=km54f4):

The highest rate is:
`Napakiak Ircinraq Power Co (99634, AK)` - `$0.839779005525`

**Here is my code and CSV image attached:**

```
import csv

def pronmpt_filename():
    filename = input("Please enter the data file: ")
    return filename

def comm_rate():
    commR_list = []
    with open(pronmpt_filename(), "r") as my_csv:
        reader = csv.DictReader(my_csv, delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            commR = row["comm_rate"]
            if commR != None and commR != "":
                commR_list.append(float(row["comm_rate"]))

    avg_commR = sum(commR_list) / len(commR_list)
    print("")
    print("The average commercial rate is: ", avg_commR)
    print("")
    print("The highest rate is: \n", max(commR_list))
    print("")
    print("The lowest rate is: \n", min(commR_list))
```

Comment: Please post the csv text (not image) so we can test. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I added the CSV file link. thanks Mike67

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using python `zip` function. Here I show you the example (I will be using `pandas` to read the csv file, you can choose as per your requirement. But I will recommend `pandas` for this type of problems):

```
import pandas as pd
read_file = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
zipped_result = [ (f, i) for f, i in zip(read_file["comm_rate"], read_file["utility_name"])]

for i,j in zipped_result:
    print(f"The highest rate is:  {j} -  {i}.")
```

Comment: Thank you E M Tonoy. That works great!!. but I have to send it through a Linux server and verify my file with one model and it doesn't admit pandas module. is there a way to do it without pandas? and if yes, an example could be fine. :)

Comment: As I said that you can use any other module as per your requirement. It is not mandatory to use pandas.

For Linux server, I can suggest `csv` module. I give an example as you want

`import csv

ifile  = open('filename.csv', "rb")


reader = csv.reader(ifile)`

Hope it will work.